# How can I bind variables for Blazegraph SELECT SPARQL query for remote repository?

Tags: sparql, sesame, openrdf, blazegraph

I can't find how to bind `SELECT` variables for Blazegraph SPARQL query for remote Repository.

Examples exist only for a local repository and with different classes.

`IPreparedTupleQuery` does not have a `bindParameters` method.

Doing `Prepare` every time takes a lot of time.

https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/RDR

```
RemoteRepository r = repositoryManager.getRepositoryForNamespace(namespace);
IPreparedTupleQuery query = r.prepareTupleQuery("SELECT ?age ?src WHERE {?bob foaf:name \"Bob\" . <<?bob foaf:age ?age>> dc:source ?src .}");
TupleQueryResult result = query.evaluate();
```

Comment: This question is not really Sesame-related. Unfortunately the Blazegraph developers chose to implement their access API in such a way that it is no longer Sesame-compatible. It superficially _looks_ like the Sesame API but it deviates in key areas from the standard.

Comment: In this particular case the problem is that their `IPreparedTupleQuery` interface doesn't actually extend Sesame's `org.openrdf.query.TupleQuery`. If it did, you could simple use `setBinding()` to add bindings to your request... It might be that they provide an alternative mechanism to achieve the same goal, but you'd be best off asking their dev/support team directly.

Comment: I see..thank you. Yeah, for org.openrdf.query.TupleQuery I can call setBinding() but for the IPreparedTupleQuery I can't... and I have not found the way how to do it..so I asked

Comment: don't get me wrong, I think it's a valid question. I only wanted to point out that despite the Sesame tag, it's really Blazegraph-specific, so a "here's how you do this in Sesame" answer won't help you. I'm not sure any Blazegraph devs are on StackOverflow, but they do have a mailinglist. If you ask there and get an answer, could you then post that answer here?

Comment: I have not found how to address Blazegraph developers.. it seems that support is not free. I also could not create 'Blazegraph' tag..

Comment: They have a free community support mailinglist. See https://www.blazegraph.com/product/support/ .